# Can I marshal my own data structures with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using my *own* **iterable** structures - various BinaryTrees. Can I simply marshal them? It's quite easy to marshal f.e. java.util.List implementations, but in my case, it's absolutely unacceptable. I need to use my own structures, with no internal containers whatsoever - only memory chains (root.leftson.rightson etc.)

In other words, is it possible to marshall structure like:

`class BinaryTree<T> implements Iterable<T>` ?

**Edit:** Structure is supposed to look like (for `BinaryTree<Person>`):

```
<persons>
 <person>
   <name>John</name>
   <surname>Black</name>
 </person>
 <person>
   <name>Joe</name>
   <surname>Blue</name>
 </person>
</persons>
```

So when I add annotation to my structure like:

```
@XmlElement
private BinaryTree<Person> persons = new BinaryTree<Person>();
public BinaryTree<Person> getPersons() { return persons; }
```

,it just creates empty element like `<persons />`. I also tried @XmlElementWrapper annotations, but it won't take custom structure (must be collection or something similar). It would be nice to have like @IterableElement or what :)

Comment: You need to ask yourself "how would this structure be represented in XML?".

Comment: I certianly know that, check edit.

Comment: What edit? I see nothing regarding your desired XML structure.

Comment: you were faster then ctrl+v :) see now

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide on how to do your own marshalling methods in the javadoc of [XMLAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). This way, using the [@XMLJavaAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) annotation, you can define exactly how you want to marshal your class.

Comment: There is also an example on my blog of using XML Adapter:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: Looks good, I'll look at it bit closer for sure. But I'm in epic hurry, so I've picked DOM this time.